# Scripting Javascript for load testing

Tags: javascript, testing, rhino, load-testing, v8

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to test my web app behaviour under heavy load. I try to minimize the amount of extra code that I'll need to write and maintain.

As the application is pretty js heavy - tons of AJAX requests and practically no full page reloads, my best bet so far is to use something like Rhino or other server side javascript environment + env-js to be able to make use of the code that sends requests from javascript.

However, a single instance of Rhino weights after loading all the code necessary about 200M. That's not very promissing as I was hoping to have at least ~20 instances open and sending requests in a loop. Is there another js engine (v8?) that is more lightweight and would suit my needs.

And finally, what do you use for testing server side of your applications under heavy load?

Comment: Which part of the application are you trying to load test - the server, or the client (the browser)?

Comment: if all you are load testing is the server, why do you need JavaScript? just load test the actual requests...

Comment: Because the requests are complicated. It's a game and to make proper requests there is a need to keep track of the current situation. There is no way to write it by hand. I want to test both GET's and POST's.

Answer (score 0):

> However, a single instance of Rhino weights after loading all the code necessary about 200M. That's not very promissing as I was hoping to have at least ~20 instances open and sending requests in a loop. Is there another js engine (v8?) that is more lightweight and would suit my needs.

- [Nashorn](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide) would be a good fit

> And finally, what do you use for testing server side of your applications under heavy load?

- [J2V8](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/11/17/highly-efficient-java-javascript-integration/) would be a good fit

**References**

- [Project Nashorn](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/january/article4.php)
- [Nashorn Extensions](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions)